# Is this how to prove a recurrence?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Given:

$U(0)=4$

$U(n+1)=3+2\cdot U(n)$   ...recurrence case

$U(n)=7\cdot 2^n-3$

My Solution:

$U(n+1)=3+2\cdot U(n)$

$\frac{U(n+1)-3}{2}=U(n)$

$\frac{U(n+1)-3}{2}=7\cdot 2^n-3$

Since I know $U(0) =4$, and with that I can solve $U(1)=11$

$n = 0$

$\frac{U(0+1)-3}{2}=7\cdot2^0-3$

$4=4$   .... is this a proof?

Comment: If you already have U(n), what else do you want to solve?

Comment: "How to prove a recurrence" is a bit vague. When you have
$$
U_{n+1} = 3 + 2U_{n}
$$
this is quite clearly a recurrence. It's not clear what is required ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a proof, but it contains the idea.

What you're doing should be formalized with induction.

**Given:** $U(0)=4$, $U(n+1)=3+2U(n)$

**Conjecture:** $U(n)=7\cdot 2^n-3$

**Base of induction:** $7\cdot2^0-3=4=U(0)$. Verified true.

**Induction step:** Assume $U(n)=7\cdot2^n-3$. Then
$$
U(n+1)=3+2U(n)=3+2(7\cdot2^n-3)=2\cdot7\cdot2^{n}+3-6=7\cdot2^{n+1}-3.
$$
End.